# A special case of dcast in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dcast

My question seems really simple, and indeed I feel very annoyed for the fact that I cannot make it work. Let's say I have a simple `dataframe` with one column for `group` and one variable `x`. Because my variable group contains a "control" condition, I would like to run a `t.test` of all my other conditions against my control variable.

```
library(data.table) # I am use to the data.table sintax, tho I will happily accept a solution in any other dialect

# Generate dummy data
set.seed(1)
 df <- data.table(x = rnorm(100), g = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 100, replace =T ))
setkey(df, g, x) # Order

 df # Inspect data
```

For that purpose, I would like to `dcast` the control group and add it as a new column. Since what I want is to run a t-test and for it, I will use the whole group, I do not mind in which order the column gets included. However, the function that I would use to change from a long format to a wide format (`dcast`), doesn't seem to work here.

```
# dcast appoach
m <- dcast(df, x ~ g) # This is just... B*#!!it
```

So here is an approximation of what I look for:

```
# Kind of what I want

# Isolate control condition
Control <- df[g == "C"] 

df[, C := rep(Control, 3)] # In this case it says there a "remainder", tho I would prefer to add NAs to the variable x until completion
```

I also would not mind having all the groups A, B and C, as columns.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what does that mean exactly. Include any error messages you get.

Comment: Sorry, I think it might be a language issue. The `dcast` function gives a perfectly fine outcome, no crashes. However, that output is not even close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Rather than 'an approximation' of what you're after, are you able to describe exactly what you want? Maybe reduce the size of your example so it's easier to construct the expected output. Also, when using `sample` you should also use `set.seed()` so the data we use is the same as yours.

Comment: EDIT: `set.seed()` added. In words, what I would like to get is a reconstruction of the data frame but with an extra column with the complete group "C". A solution could be to have a new resulting dataset with three columns "A", "B" and "C". The order in which each row/datapoint is included is not relevant. When one of the groups is longer than the others, then, NAs should be included.

Comment: is it something like `cbind(df[g != "C"], df[g == "C"])` that you're after?

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase: "maybe it's an A/B problem".  It starts with "How can I do B with A?" Means you have chosen the wrong method to do B. Also possibly means that you should spend more effort describing the current situation and exactly what needs to be done and less effort on trying to mandate that R function used to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this might be what the OP has asked for:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df, rowid(g) ~ g, value.var = "x")
```

> ```
>      g            A           B           C
>  1:  1 -1.804958629 -1.98935170 -2.21469989
>  2:  2 -1.470752384 -1.52356680 -0.74327321
>  3:  3 -1.276592208 -1.37705956 -0.62124058
>  4:  4 -1.253633400 -1.12936310 -0.61202639
>  5:  5 -1.224612615 -1.04413463 -0.58952095
>  6:  6 -0.934097632 -0.83562861 -0.47340064
>  7:  7 -0.709946431 -0.82046838 -0.41499456
>  8:  8 -0.707495157 -0.68875569 -0.39428995
>  9:  9 -0.626453811 -0.47815006 -0.30538839
> 10: 10 -0.573265414 -0.25336168 -0.13505460
> 11: 11 -0.568668733 -0.13517862  0.02800216
> 12: 12 -0.542520031 -0.11234621  0.39810588
> 13: 13 -0.443291873 -0.05931340  0.41794156
> 14: 14 -0.367221476 -0.05612874  0.55848643
> 15: 15 -0.304183924 -0.05380504  0.61982575
> 16: 16 -0.164523596 -0.01619026  0.69696338
> 17: 17 -0.155795507  0.07434132  0.82122120
> 18: 18 -0.102787727  0.15325334  0.88110773
> 19: 19 -0.044933609  0.34111969  0.94383621
> 20: 20 -0.039240003  0.36458196  1.12493092
> 21: 21  0.001105352  0.38767161  1.16040262
> 22: 22  0.074564983  0.48742905  1.17808700
> 23: 23  0.183643324  0.56971963  1.46555486
> 24: 24  0.188792300  0.59390132  1.51178117
> 25: 25  0.267098791  0.61072635          NA
> 26: 26  0.291446236  0.76317575          NA
> 27: 27  0.329507772  1.10002537          NA
> 28: 28  0.332950371  1.35867955          NA
> 29: 29  0.370018810  1.43302370          NA
> 30: 30  0.389843236  1.58683345          NA
> 31: 31  0.475509529  2.40161776          NA
> 32: 32  0.556663199          NA          NA
> 33: 33  0.575781352          NA          NA
> 34: 34  0.593946188          NA          NA
> 35: 35  0.689739362          NA          NA
> 36: 36  0.700213650          NA          NA
> 37: 37  0.738324705          NA          NA
> 38: 38  0.768532925          NA          NA
> 39: 39  0.782136301          NA          NA
> 40: 40  0.918977372          NA          NA
> 41: 41  1.063099837          NA          NA
> 42: 42  1.207867806          NA          NA
> 43: 43  1.595280802          NA          NA
> 44: 44  1.980399899          NA          NA
> 45: 45  2.172611670          NA          NA
>      g            A           B           C
> ```

This works by artificially introducing an individual row count `rowid(g)` for each group.

However, in line with [42-'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777322/a-special-case-of-dcast-in-r#comment84559929_48777322), I do not understand how this will help to solve OP's underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks! I think `rowid` will become one of my best friends!!